# Twilio programmable SMS not sending in deployed Lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, twilio, serverless, twilio-api

I am working on a [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) AWS service that uses [Twilio's programmable SMS](https://www.twilio.com/sms) to deliver text messages.

My setup is consistently delivering messages successfully when I run the stack locally (e.g. `sls offline start`), but in the deployed environment I seem to be unable to even call the method on the [Twilio client](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/examples/example.js#L40).

Here's how the message delivery is set up:

```js
const twilio = require('twilio');

const twilioClient = twilio(
  process.env.TWILIO_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_TOKEN,
  {
    lazyLoading: true,
  }
);

export function sendMessage(user, message) {
  twilioClient.messages.create({
    from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
    to: user.phone,
    body: message,
  }, function(err, message) {
    console.log('error', err);
    console.log('message', message);
  });
}

// And then usage in a Serverless Function Handler

function example(event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  // user is also determined here
  sendMessage(user, 'This is a message');

  return {
    body: JSON.stringify({}),
    statusCode: 200
  };
}
```

Locally, running this works and I am able to see the output of the `message` log, with nothing on the `error` log. However, when deployed, running this yields nothing -- the method appears to not even get called (and I can verify in the Twilio logs that no API call was made), therefor no `error` or `message` logs are made in the callback.

In debugging I've tried the following:

- I've logged all the environment variables (Twilio SSID, auth token, phone number), as well as the function arguments, and they all appear to be in place. I also checked out the Lambda function itself to make sure the environment variables exist.
- I've examined my CloudWatch logs; no errors or exceptions are logged. Other than the Twilio method not getting called the Lambda function is executed without issue.
- I've tried logging things like `twilio` and `twilioClient.messages.create` to make sure the client and function definition didn't get wiped out somehow.
- I thought maybe it had to do with `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` so I changing it from `false` to `true`.

I have come up empty, I can't figure out why this would be working locally, but not when deployed.

---

Edit: per the [Twilio client example](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/examples/example.js#L50), if you omit the callback function the method will return a Promise. I went ahead and tried to await the response of the method:

```js
export function sendMessage(user, message) {
  return twilioClient.messages.create({
    from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER!,
    to: user.phone,
    body: message,
  });
}

// Usage...

async function example(event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  try {
    const message = await sendMessage(user, 'This is a message');
    console.log('message', message)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }

  return {
    body: JSON.stringify({}),
    statusCode: 200
  };
}
```

In this example the Lambda function is successful, but neither the message nor the error are logged.

Comment: I haven't used Lambda but with Twilio Functions, you need to me mindful of asynchronous functions and and the associate callback to indicate the end of the function - specifically - https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#callback-and-asynchronous-limitations. Could this be what is going on in this case as well? Maybe some details here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Comment: @Alan I suspect you are on to something, but I unfortunately have not been able to solve it. I've updated my question to note that I've given a Promise-based method a shot, with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this and it works. I tried to make my code as similar to use, with a few changes.

```
const twilio = require('twilio');

const twilioClient = twilio(
  process.env.TWILIO_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_TOKEN
);

let user = '+14075551212';

function sendMessage(user, message) {
  return twilioClient.messages.create({
    from: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
    to: user,
    body: message,
  });
}

exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  try {
    const message = await sendMessage(user, 'This is a message');
    console.log('message', message);
    callback(null, {result: 'success'});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
    callback("error");
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Alan! Sure enough, like you mentioned, this works as written. I'm going to mark this as the answer. Unfortunately, in my case, I think there's something else going on, and I think it's the VPC I have set up on the Lambda function. It's needed to communicate with an RDS instance, and I think somewhere in there it's blocking outbound requests to Twilio. I neglected to mention this in my original post, apologies. If you have any VPC / Subnet / NAT gateway knowledge, I'm all ears. Otherwise, thanks for this answer!

Comment: Hi Jody, I do but not my speciality. It may be best for another post. A diagram of your topology would help others provide a more focused answer. I would normally think IAM permissions is more an issue with Lambda but I have not really worked that much with it, 100% on my growing to-do list though.

Comment: It was the `await` that I needed. Thanks!